# Can a single Subversion repository managed as multiple projects in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, projects

I have a Helpdesk application that contains modules that can be downloaded and installed separately as required / preferred by the users. The structure is very similar to many software such as Drupal, which modules can be loaded/unloaded easily.

I'm using a single SVN repository for this Helpdesk application and create different tags for each module. And on my Eclipse I have everything as a single project.

- My question is, can a single Subversion repository managed as multiple projects in Eclipse?
- Can I create one Eclipse project for the whole application and at the same time for each module?
- Another requirement is that by splitting each module as a different project would make Eclipse builds faster.

The reason is, I want to delegate programming work of each module to another person without the need to expose everything. The person would only see & work on the module only but commit to the main repository.

I know that Eclipse will have configuration files for every project, would there be any conflict.

Answer (score 2):

I've had good look storing multiple Eclipse projects in one repository. Each of the projects is stored in a separate folder under the repository's root. Then, I use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) to check out each of those folders as a separate Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that you should nest Eclipse projects (so that a master project contains many sub-projects).

Instead of the master project, you could group the individual projects into what Eclipse calls a Team Project Set (found in the Export/Import menus). This is an XML file that defines where all the projects are. You can put that file into Subversion as well.

So, you would have all the module's projects, and that XML file (which is not a project itself), all in Subversion (could be the same repository, could be spread over several).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is strictly possible. Personally, I would split the modules up into different projects entirely, and I would probably use Eclipse's plugin structure to resolve dependencies between them and the main project. If you ship the plugins as jars, they're still modular. Then, you can control each plugin as a separate project in Eclipse, and a separate folder in SVN.

Answer (score 0):

That is no problem at all! Just create your trunk/tags/branches structure on your svn repo. Create your differen projects and then check thos projects into your trunc folder on your svn system. Finished!